# After the reappearance of Imam Mahdi, Will the world (life) be continued for a long period of time or not?

Tags: shia-sunni, life, imam-mahdi

According to the perspective of Shiite, Imam Mahdi (a.j.) (another name: Imam Zaman) will reappear as the last Imam of Shiite to save the world from the oppression. I'd like to know what will precisely occur. Actually I mean will the world be finished after a short and limited time (by governorship of him)? (As a world which would be without any oppression)

Or the world is going to begin a new and long period of life that won't be clear when it is going to be finished? (Sunni view)

Note: On the whole, I am looking for Sunni view about the mentioned issue, even though they agree the matter by another name (except Mahdi) as the savior of the world. (Perhaps some or many of them agree with the name of Mahdi as well).

Comment: The answer which is below which has the Hadith, is the only knowledge we have about the future and nothing more I guess. So, we don't what's gonna happen in the future.

Comment: Eternal life! Why keep suffering again and again?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Sunni view (I am not aware of the Shia view), Imam Mahdi will come in a time of great distress. He will lead the Muslims until the appearance of Jesus Christ (peace be upon him) who will lead an army of Muslims to kill the dajjal (anti-Christ). Jesus will then rule over the Muslims until he dies of a natural death. Several major signs of the day of judgement will follow thereafter. Only then will the world come to an end.

So, in short, the world will not end immediately after the appearance of Imam Mahdi.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Shia narratives, the world has some main attributes on the eve of Mahdi advent, like The intrusive and oppressive tyranny that enters every house. when The mahdi appear, jesus christ appears too, and pray behind the mahdi. and then world became mahdi's government, without any big war. only fight is with dajjal who rise against mahdi. and according to some narratives, this uprising will last 8 month.
but about the term of Imam Mahdi's rule, we can't be sure. stories are different. some hadiths say it will last 7 or 9 years. in a hadith of imam Sadegh he said:

> (سبع سنین یکون سبعین سنة من سنیکم هذه (منتخب الاثر

which means every year in imam mahdi government is equal of 10 year. so it will last 70 year. and I heard from Ali Al-Kourani, meaning of year in these hadiths can be century, 7 century.
in some other hadiths they say it will last until doomsday which we can imagine it will be too long.
so, we cant be sure about that, but most valid hadiths in shia books, say 7 or 70 year.